# How to remove "pause slide" from beamer-like presentation when you don't have the sources

Tags: beamer

Lot's of my teachers give us some slides, built with beamer, but the sources are never included. And to print it, I like to remove the useless slides that are created using `\pause`-like commands.

I tried to find some solution to remove them automatically, but because I never found a good solution, I decided to write my own solution that I share in the answer. If you have a better way to proceed/a more straight forward solution, don't hesitate to add it !

Answer (score 3):

I came up with this solution, that is a one-line bash command (you can easily change it into an alias/bash script). The idea is to take always the last slide when several slides have the same page number. The problem is that if the same slide display two different things on the same "page", then only the last one is kept.

```
INPUT=mpri_clp1.pdf; OUTPUT=mpri_clp1_out2.pdf; (pdftk ${INPUT} dump_data | egrep "PageLabelNewIndex" | sed 's/[^0-9]//g' | sed '1d' | sed -r 's/(.*)/echo $((\1-1))/ge') | tr '\n' ' ' | xargs -I{} echo "pdftk \"${INPUT}\" cat {} end output \"${OUTPUT}\"" | bash
```