# How to remove beamer overlays in received PDF?

Tags: beamer

I often receive PDF files, where the lecturer was too lazy to recompile their beamer files with 'handout' option before delivery.

Is there a way to automatically remove these overlays out of the received PDF files, just keeping the slides which are showing the full content?

Comment: If you had the frame counter, you could throw out duplicates, but PDFs don't store frame counters (except possibly as anchor names).

Comment: Not sure this is always relevant, there may be overlapping content anyway

Comment: @BambOo: There *can* be additional overlapping content, but for generated overlays, you can be sure it overlaps, and (e.g. having many slides with long lists of hidden enumeration items) it's quite an effort to remove 80% of the sub-slides per hand, while having to be careful not to remove too much. Do this for 5-10 lectures a week, which all have more than 100 slides, and this question gets very relevant ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A very beginning of an answer**

I looked a bit on the vast ocean of the web how to handle pdf files with something else than LaTeX since you only have the pdf output. 
I figured it would be simpler to use a `python`-based script, but once again it is just a proposal.

After digging a bit here is what comes out combining two StackOverflow solutions :

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/39574231/9576551
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12360999/retrieve-page-numbers-from-document-with-pypdf/35728954

Combining the two solutions I propose this python script which

1. Retrieves the number of the first page associated with a `frame`
2. Applies the appropriate shifts to get the number of the last page associated with the previous `frame`
3. Concatenates only these frames in a new file

In my example it seems beamer stores `frame` begin page number as

```
infile.trailer["/Root"]["/PageLabels"]["/Nums"]
```

which returns

> [0, {'/P': '1'}, 5, {'/P': '2'}, 7, {'/P': '3'}]

Here is the python script

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
# Read pdf from file
infile = PdfFileReader('test.pdf')
# Get total amount of pages
totpages = infile.getNumPages()
# Get starting page number from each page
pdfpagenuminfo = infile.trailer["/Root"]["/PageLabels"]["/Nums"]
pdfpagenumaliases = pdfpagenuminfo[0::2]
# Shift page number of interest to get only the page of the last overlay for each frame 
pagestokeep = [x-1 for x in pdfpagenumaliases[1::]] + [totpages-1]

# Initialize output
output = PdfFileWriter()
# Add content to output
for i in pagestokeep:
    p = infile.getPage(i)
    output.addPage(p)
# Write to output file
with open('newfile.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    output.write(f)
```

Here is the beamer example i used to test it

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}
 \begin{itemize}[<+->]
     \item 1
     \item 2
     \item 3
     \item 4
     \item 5
 \end{itemize}   
 \end{frame}

 \begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
        \item 1
        \item 2
    \end{itemize}   
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{itemize}[<+->]
            \item 1
            \item 2
        \end{itemize}   
        \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pdftk` for that: ([from this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/402074/261387))

```
#! /bin/bash

INPUT=$1
OUTPUT=$2

PAGE_NUMBERS=$((pdftk ${INPUT} dump_data | egrep "PageLabelNewIndex" | sed 's/[^0-9]//g' | sed '1d' | sed -r 's/(.*)/echo $((\1-1))/ge') | tr '\n' ' ')

pdftk ${INPUT} cat $PAGE_NUMBERS end output ${OUTPUT}
```

It selects the last page from multiple pages having the same number.